# Can not view findBySql results

Tags: php, yii

In controller I write following

```
$types=Types::model()->findBySql('SELECT t_id, t_name FROM ygs_types');
$this->render('index', array('types'=>$types));
```

In view

```
$list = CHtml::listData($types, 't_id', 't_name');
foreach($list as $type) {
    echo '<p>'.$type.'</p>';
}
```

but I can not see any results.

If I write in controller

```
$typeModel = new Types();
$types = $typeModel->findAll();
$this->render('index', array('types'=>$types));
```

I see a list of results.
The query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `findAllBySql` instead of `findBySql` like below:

```
$types=Types::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT t_id, t_name FROM ygs_types');
```

Now, you can see your desired result.